# How to colour the US map with Yellow, Green, Red and Blue to minimize the number of states with the color of Green

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, coloring

I want to colour the US (only the states) map with Yellow, Green, Red and Blue. I was wondering what would be the lowest number of states with the colour of Green. We can of course use the other colours as much as we want. Please note that I want to follow the Four Color Theorem rules.

Motivation:
I am studying graph theory and I want to know if there is a way that we could limit the use of the fourth colour as much as possible. This is not a homework problem.

My attempt:
I have tried many variations and can limit it to 6 and it seems like the 
minimum possible but there are many possibilities to try ($4^{50}$). Therefore I was wondering if there is a simpler method? Thank you in advance.

Clarification:
I am interested in only the mainland of USA. For states like Michigan that are split, I used the same colour for both parts.

Comment: you would need to agree on a favorite version of the graph. In the actual US, there are islands, states split into disconnected regions, other things forbidden

Comment: https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2006/05/four-coloring-united-states.html  They correctly point out that three colors cannot work, as Nevada has an odd number of neighbors

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I made a few clarifications.

Comment: @WillJagy Maine has an odd number of neighbours too, but that's not much of a problem.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The precise obstacle is "an odd number of neighbors forming a cycle". So coastal states, or states bordering Mexico or Canada, are never going to present a local obstacle. (Other such states are CA, LA, ND, and maybe others I've missed.) Of course it's also possible that some further global obstruction exists that can't be detected by looking at some state and its neighbors: that just doesn't happen to be the case for the actual map of the United States.

Comment: There are not infinite possibilities. There is only $4^{50}$ ways of assigning colors to all the states even if we consider no other constraints or symmetries.

Comment: @DerekElkins thank you for your correction. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The minimum is **two states** that use the fourth color. Nevada and its five neighbors cannot be colored with only three colors, and similarly West Virginia and its five neighbors cannot be colored with only three colors. In both cases, once you color the center state one color (say, red), you can't use it again on its neighbors: without using green, they'd have to alternate yellow-blue-yellow-blue, but because the number of neighbors is odd, you'd get stuck at the end.

(In the comments, David K points out that Kentucky is a third state with the same problem: it has seven neighbors. But this doesn't force us to use a third green state, because Kentucky and West Virginia share a border and some common neighbors.)

Using only two green states is possible. If we color Arizona (dealing with the Nevada situation) and Ohio (dealing with West Virginia and Kentucky) both green, then the remainder of the map can be completed using only blue, red, and yellow:

[image]

Adjacencies between the states may be easier to see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContiguousUSAGraph.html).

Comment: I need a better atlas. I'm looking at the Philadelphia area, I cannot tell what happens among Pennsylvania, New Jersey, Delaware, Maryland.

Comment: @WillJagy The reference I actually used to color the US was [this picture of the US graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContiguousUSAGraph.html), which solves this problem.

Comment: That's pretty good. A simple standard: at least one drivable road between neighbors

Comment: just curious -- did you write code to do this, or did you do this by hand?

Comment: @antkam By hand. I found two subgraphs where a fourth color is forced, and chose a state from each of them to color green that seemed to be a good choice. Then I just tried to color the rest with three colors - and for that, once you color the first two states, most of the rest of the map is forced, except for a few states like Maine.

Comment: @WillJagy NJ and MD don't touch because DE interposes. All the other edges exist.

Comment: Kentucky has seven neighbors, but coloring Ohio green fixes that as well as WV. I also notice that you managed to use four colors for UT, CO, AZ, and NM, which makes the map a little clearer but I think is not strictly required by the usual rules, that is, under the usual rules (as far as I know) you could make AZ yellow and CA green.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for pointing this out - I didn't even notice, so I got a bit lucky with the choice of state in the WV cluster that I colored green.

Comment: Point of scientific interest: points such as the Four Corners https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Corners_Monument happen only when legislated by humans. In nature, existing edges, such as riverbeds, split on one side in an orthogonal manner, creating a T junction that is, well, typically fractal. One can do an experiment with a plate of wet clay, heat it under a lamp, and watch edges appear as the mud dries out. I will try to find out the name for this...

Comment: Funnily enough, once you choose the two green countries, the colouring is basically unique.

Comment: In third edition of Mathematical Snapshots by H. Steinhaus, pages 88-89, photographs 98 and 99  https://books.google.com/books?id=sFzCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: You're lucky this question is tagged graph theory or I'd be complaining about the white outer area.